# What is the difference between sqldeveloper.exe and sqldeveloperW.exe?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

My antivirus blocking sqldeveloperw.exe and allowing sqldeveper.exe. I want to know the difference between these.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

One prints debug info to the console when you run it (sqldeveloperw.exe) and one doesn't (sqldeveloper.exe)

You should always run the sqldeveloper.exe in the base directory unless instructed otherwise by support/R&D to run something out of the bin directory for debugging purposes.